# Bootstrap Toggle Not working on disabled-enabled with limited elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, angular-bootstrap-toggle

I am using Bootstrap Toggle Library with Bootstrap4 but I have problems when I try to control that user only switch 'ON' a limited number of elements. Here is my HTML code:

```
<div style="border:solid border-width: 1px;">
       <li class="ui-state-default">
           <input type="checkbox" name="checkImg" data-height="10" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini"data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
                 Option 1
    </li> </div>
```

All 11 elements has the same code, and my Jquery:

```
$('input[name="checkImg"]').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($('input[name="checkImg"]:checked').length > 3 ) {
          console.log("In Condition");
          $(this).prop('checked', false);   
     }                        
   });
```

Here is a photo of the result when I switch 4 elements to 'ON':
[image]

I can see that condition is right and detect when 3 elements are switch 'ON' but I cant disabled the rest of 'False' input until some of 'On' Elements switch to 'OFF'. Anyone can help?

In addition, I use disabled from bootstrap but not worked.

Thanks for all.

Edit:

https://jsfiddle.net/5vr0c3w2/14/

Comment: Please attache jsfiddle with working example and we will be able to fix your code.

Comment: I Attache it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your script.
try to change this:

```
$('input[name=checkImg]')
```

to this

```
$('input[name="checkImg"]')
```

I tried correcting this and the script seems to work now.

EDIT: I see the problem is with Bootstrap-toggle, that uses a different kind of approach for checking and unchecking checkboxes.

Instead of just unchecking the checkbox you also have to change its parent div's class from "btn-success" to "btn-danger off". Now this code snippet should work for you as well.

```js
$('input[name="checkImg"]').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($('input[name="checkImg"]:checked').length > 3 ) {
        console.log("You can select no more than 3 options");
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        $(this).parent().removeClass("btn-success");
        $(this).parent().addClass("btn-default off");
    }                        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Primera Fila -->
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header colorPlataforma">Imagenes Disponibles</div>
      <div class="card-body fuenteTabla">
        <div class="overflow">
          <ul class="justify-content-center col-12 connectedSortable" id="sortable1">
            <div style="border:solid border-width: 1px;">
              <li class="ui-state-default">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkImg" data-height="10" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini"
                data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
                Option 1
              </li>
            </div>
            <div style="border:solid border-width: 1px;">
              <li class="ui-state-default"> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkImg" data-height="10" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini"
                data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
                Option 2
              </li>
            </div>
            <div style="border:solid border-width: 1px;">
              <li class="ui-state-default"> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkImg" data-height="10" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini"
                data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
                Option 3 
              </li>
            </div>
            <div style="border:solid border-width: 1px;">
              <li class="ui-state-default"> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkImg" data-height="10" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini"
                data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
                Option 4
              </li>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I change it, but it still do the same. Thanks for correction.

Comment: The problem is on the bootstrap-toggle I think, as you can see in my code that not works: https://jsfiddle.net/5vr0c3w2/14/

Comment: Well you did it. Awsome answer, works perfectly. Thanks for all.